# Google maps - Query to geocode returns incorrect results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Searching for '31708' returns results with the right postal_code

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D31707

Searching for '31707' returns results in a different postal_code

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D31708

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add "zipcode" to the query (if you know it is going to be a zipcode).

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3Dzipcode+31707